# Creating eventlog in registry using PowerShell creates unwanted source with the same name as logname

Tags: powershell, .net-4.8

I try to add eventlog for .net framework using powershell.

When I run the following command in PowerShell to create a new event log

**New-EventLog -source "src1" -LogName "myTest"**

in the registry I See the following hierarchy

**myTest  -->  myTest and src1**

See below image

[image]
I do not want the second **mytest** entry  . The hierarchy should be
**myTest --> src1**

I tried to remove this unwanted source using

**Remove-EventLog -Source 'myTest'**
[image]

I get the following error:

Remove-EventLog : The event log source 'myTest' cannot be deleted, because it's equal to the log name.
At line:1 char:1

- Remove-EventLog -Source 'myTest'
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-EventLog], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveEventLogCommand
  ```

Any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: This seems to be the default behavior. Why do you want to "fix" it? Does it cause any issues?

Comment: I see many have the same setup but there are some that don't. For instance "Key Management Service" doesn't

Comment: We used to create the same thing in the registry with .reg file and never had that extra entry that is why i want to remove it. Also we only log src1(this is my wcf service) not mytest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just delete it manually, not sure what the ramifications are.

```
Remove-Item hklm:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\EventLog\mytest\mytest
```

It appears that's where any custom category, parameter, or message resource files would be configured.